# Laravel 5 - How to check username & password is match with table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created the below login form in `Laravel 5` and I want to simply check if the username & password matches with that of the database table and if so, redirect to the dashboard page else stay on the login page. I am also trying to find the solution by myself but I am posting this question to get an idea of how to do these things in `Laravel 5`.

Any idea??

### 2015_09_10_050324_admin_details.php (migrations)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AdminDetails extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admin_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('admin_details');
    }
}
```

### Database structure

[image]

[image]

### login.blade.php (view)

```
<form name="frmLogin" action="{{ URL::to('administrator/userAuthentication') }}" method="post">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Login</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```

### AdminLoginController.php (controller)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\AdminLoginModel;


class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('backend.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt for admin user.
     *
     */
    public function userAuthentication(Request $request)
    {

        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password))){
            return "success";
        }else{
            return "Wrong Credentials";
        }
        die;
    }
}
```

---

### AdminLoginModel.php (model)

```
    <?php
/*namespace App;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;*/

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class AdminLoginModel extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'admin_details';
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];
}
```

### routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('dashboard','DashboardController');
Route::resource('administrator','AdminLoginController');
Route::resource('users','AdminLoginController');
Route::resource('administrator/userAuthentication', 'AdminLoginController@userAuthentication');
```

Comment: Can i see your routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

**login.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Login Form</h3>  

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('UserName') !!}
    {!! Form::text('username', null,
        array(
              'class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder'=>'Your UserName')) !!}
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('password') !!}
    {!! Form::text('password', null,
        array(
              'class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder'=>'Your Password')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Login',
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model:-**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class UserRegisters extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract { 
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    protected $table = 'userregisters';
    protected $fillable = ['user_name', 'password'];
}
?>
```

**Controller:-**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\UserRegisters;
use App\UserProfiles;
use Validator;
use View;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Redirect;
use Session;
use Hash;
use DB;

class UserRegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Login a Registered Users.
     *
     */
    public function login(){
        $uname = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
            if (Auth::attempt(array('user_name' => $uname, 'password' => $password))){
            return "success";
            }
            else {        
                return "Wrong Credentials";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**route:-**

```
Route::post('/login', 'UserRegisterController@login');
```

**migration:-**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Userregisters extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('userregisters', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name', 128);
            $table->string('last_name', 128);
            $table->string('user_name', 128);
            $table->string('password', 128);
            $table->string('email', 128);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('userregisters');
    }
}
```

let me know if there any errors.

Comment: I am trying with your code and added html first and when I hit the page I am getting only this html `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Login Form</h3>`

Comment: are you not getting any login form?

Comment: No. I am getting only `Login Form` text :(

Comment: are you using laravel 5?  and paste this code in your login.blade.php file.

Comment: Yes I am using Laravel 5 version and I have added your HTML code inside `login.blade.php` file.

Comment: go to your app\config folder just change app.php file in         Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

Comment: in  Laravel Framework Service Providers add these lines of code           Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

Comment: in Class Aliases add this lines of code    'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
  'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'

Comment: 1. added `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class, Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` inside aliases 2. added `'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 'HTML' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',` inside aliases but now getting white blank page :(

Comment: just read my above two messages properly and add same places.

Comment: Autoloaded Service Providers add these lines of code Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class, Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class

Comment: in Class Aliases add this lines of code 'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'

Comment: i have edited my answer just look at login form and try now.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found`

Comment: have you seen this class( Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class) in your app.php file?

Comment: after that line just add (Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,) this one and try.

Comment: I have already `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` inside `providers`

Comment: this two lines also added(  'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
  'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade') in class aliases???

Comment: Yes I have added `'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
        'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',` inside `aliases`

Comment: now open composer.json file add this line in after line number 9("illuminate/html": "5.0.*")

Comment: inside this `"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    },` ???

Comment: and run the composer update in command line and try the form.

Comment: getting this error. check this screen shot: `https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/283003/0OpUvomQwm3SyU3aNF5SH9CfqgSUkDOH/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89271/discussion-between-user-and-mr-happy).

Comment: Hi. I have tried you code but every time `Auth::attempt` going to else condition. Can you explain me why. I have also updated my question with your code.

Comment: Yes,it's always go to else block only,because your auth.php file having default table users.thats  why that taking that table values.

Comment: just go to config\app folder and auth.php change model class name and table name and try.

Comment: oh okay. i have changed like this: `'model' => App\AdminLoginModel::class,` & `'table' => 'admin_details',` but now I ma getting this error: `ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 110: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\YCAdminModel given, called in /var/www/html/your-creatrs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php on line 390 and defined`

Answer (score 6):

try using auth attempt

```
    $email=$request->email;
    $password=$request->password;

     if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]))
       {
                return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
         }
```

this will check authentication

Here you can read official documentation

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

**Update**

first you need to create table called `users`

```
id|username|password|email|remember_token|created_at|updated_at
```

then in your user model

```
protected $table = 'users';

  protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
```

whichever column you want to insert data that should write in fillable array and created_at and updated_at type is datatime in mysql so it automatically insert data and time

In your  user controller

```
 public function loginPost(Request $request)
        {
            $email=$request->email;
            $password=$request->password;
           if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]))
           {
                return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
           }

           return Redirect::to('login');
        }
```

and note that auth::attempt will automatically hash password so you no need to hash password.

Before login authentication insert one record and Hash password.

```
$data=[];
$data['email']=$request->email;
$data['password']=Hash::make($password);
User::create($data);
```

update 2

```
  public function insert()
    {
         $data=[];
    $data['email']=$request->email;
    $data['password']=Hash::make($password);
    AdminLoginModel::create($data);
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick response but I don't understand(I am new with laravel) so is it possible to you for provide example regarding my question. :)

Comment: where I have to store this?? in my controller??

Comment: Regarding this `auth::attempt will automatically hash password so you no need to hash password` I have created table using with migration then I have added on dummy user record using with phpmyadmin so I don't have password in hash so how to do that??

Comment: auth attempt only when login not using registration.first you insert record using laravel registation form

Comment: $data=[]; $password='1234';
$data['email']=example@gmail.com;
$data['password']=Hash::make($password);
User::create($data);

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question with your answer so can you please check because it not redirecting.

Comment: can you post insert record and also remove echo "Done";
            die;

Comment: now just echo inside auth::attempt.check whether it display done or not

Comment: Nothing is printing inside Auth :(

Comment: how you inserted recod ?can you post your insert record code

Comment: I have added this code to insert one record `$data=[];
        $data['username'] = $request->username;
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($username);
        admin_details::create($data);` Before Auth::attempt. But record not inserting. i have added this code in my question also.

Answer (score 3):

this if non-model

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $password = $request->input('password');

   $user = DB::table('user')->where('email',$email)->first();

   if (Hash::check($password, $user->password)){
       $apiToken = base64_encode(Str::random(40));

       DB::table('user')->where('email',$email)->update([
            'api_token' => $apiToken
       ]);

       return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Login Success!',
        'data' => [
            'user' => $user,
            'api_token' => $apiToken
        ]
        ], 201);
   } else {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Login  fail!',
    ], 400);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

first import

```
use Hash;
```

then encode your password with Hash

```
Hash::make($input['password']);
```

finally check your password and email like this

```
$model = YourModelHere::where('email', $request->email)->first();
if (Hash::check($request->password, $model->password, [])) {
    // success
}
//failed
```

Comment: Trying to get property  of non-object. Why?